# Not sufficient precision calculating the hitpoint in rendering algorithm

Tags: c#, raytracing

May I ask you for piece of advice writing my raytracer in c#. Here's the rpoblem:

I've got a problem detecting hits of the rays and geometry in  my raytracer. I've implemented several functions based on this articles: https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/ray-tracing-rendering-a-triangle/ray-triangle-intersection-geometric-solution

Here's the code of calculating hitpoint:

```
 public Vector3 GetHitPoint(Vector3 origin, Vector3 ray)
        {
            float D = Vector3.Dot(this.GetNormal(), vertices[0]);
            float up = Vector3.Dot(this.GetNormal(), origin);
            up = -1 * (up + D); //50
            float down =Vector3.Dot(this.GetNormal(), ray); //0.999975
            float t =  up / -1* down; //50,00125003125078
            Console.WriteLine(origin + Vector3.Multiply(t, ray));
            return origin + Vector3.Multiply(t, ray);
        }
```

Not very elegant, but shall work. I've got the problem with precision. I've prepared test triangle that is located perpendicular to camera (center -> 0,0,50). The code calculates the point of intersection between  triangle and ray.
Origin stands for camera position, ray is the normalized vector that comes from camera to geometry, vertices[0] is the position of vertex and GetNormal() function gives correct normal vector of triangle. The problem in this case is the precision of calculation. After doing all these calculation, my hitpoint has the z coordinate of 49.99975 instead of 50.0.

This is a problem, because I use another algorithm (based on baricentric coordinates) in order to check if hitpoint is inside the triangle.

```
public bool CheckHitPoint(Vector3 P)
        {
            Vector3 v0 = vertices[1] - vertices[0];
            Vector3 v1 = vertices[2] - vertices[0];
            Vector3 v2 = P - vertices[0];
            float d00 = Vector3.Dot(v0, v0);
            float d01 = Vector3.Dot(v0, v1);
            float d11 = Vector3.Dot(v1, v1);
            float d20 = Vector3.Dot(v2, v0);
            float d21 = Vector3.Dot(v2, v1);

            float denom = d00 * d11 - d01 * d01;
            float v = (d11 * d20 - d01 * d21);
            float w = (d00 * d21 - d01 * d20);
            float u =  1.0f - v - w;
            if (u < 0 || v < 0 || w < 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else if (u > 1 || v > 1 || w > 1)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else return true;

        }
```

The conditions in algorithm and in the article is the same, but because of inaccurate result of previous function, u v w coefficients are completely wrong (since hitpoint is actually in front of the triangle).

Can I ask you to help me fixing the precision issue in the first algorithm, or introduce some kind of bias into the second algorithm, so I can get the precise hitpoint and successfully detect it inside triangle?

EDIT: Sorry, I thought that problem is preety much clear. Let me explain it deeper. Let's see the triangle:

```
Vector3[] vertices =
            {
                new Vector3(-5,-5,50),
                new Vector3(5,-5,50),
                new Vector3(0,5,50)
            };
            Vector3[] normals =
            {
                new Vector3(0,0,-1),
                new Vector3(0,0,-1),
                new Vector3(0,0,-1)
            };
```

It is clear that Normal Vector for this triangle is n(0,0,-1) and in combination with any point on it's surface, it may describe mathematically the surface.

D is the distance between between (0,0,0) and point on surface, that the triangle lies on. Since the surface may be described as a pair of parameters (normal vector and any point on surface), dot product of these parameter describes D.

Next four lines describes the equation:
t = N(A,B,C)⋅O + D/−N(A,B,C)⋅R

where

N(A,B,C) - normal vector of triangle

O - camera Position

D - Distance from (0,0,0) to surface

R - Normalized Ray Vector

Equation calculates the distance from camera position to point of intersection.

Following these equations, with triangle parameters I attached and camera position (0,0,0) poinitng at (0,0,50) the return value shall be the point with coordinates (x,y,50), no matter what is the pixel I create the ray for.
The problem is, vector methods in c# generally use floats for computations, and this is why the z coordinate is close, but not precisely 50.
Mathematically this is 100% correct, but the precision is poor.

This makes a problem, when I try to check, if the point lies inside triangle using transformation to baricentric coordinates.
The second method is ok mathematically too. Provided that Hitpoint is on the surface, if all coordinates are between 0 and 1 that means that point lies on the triangle. Details here: https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/ray-tracing-rendering-a-triangle/barycentric-coordinates

If only I could precisely count the coordinates from previous method, that would work. The problem is, because of lack of precision, the hitpoint is slightly on top or below the surface, and baricentric coordinates have crazy values.

The question is, how can I make the first method to be more precise, that means reproduce the t - distance between camera and hitpoint to be enough precise to be 50. What solution would be the best, rounding, creating custom methods for vectors replacing the built-in float-based methods or maybe some algorithm modification?
Would be grateful, if someone with experience with raytracers would gave me the piece of advice.

Comment: It is not clear what sort of help you need. As a start, have you tried simply using `double` instead of `float`? There is not enough information in your question to understand exactly what the precision-related issue is. Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem, along with a detailed explanation of what that code does, what you expect it to do instead, what you've done so far to try to fix it, and what _specificially_ need help with. See also [ask] for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: Any way to just draw HUD elements to a flat 2D projection on top of the 3D part?  That's usually how I handled that sort of rendering issue.  Also, don't use the output of the HP render for game logic, use the HP in memory instead.

Comment: I edited the topic, hope it is more clear now. You see, the topic is complicated mathematically, but the activities are mathematically ok. Precision is the problem here, even when used doubles. I would love to see how others make theyre raytracers. If there's no other way, I would use other method I used before (without baricentric values), but it is much less optimal. ;(